# Unity 3D - CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle

Stuck in a problem from past two days, Also re-installed the sdk but no success.
1. Checked the Build-Tools Folder , there is a folder: 27.0.3.
2. I am using Unity 2018.1.1f1.
3. Have been using JDK: "jdk1.8.0_172".
4. Working on Windows 10.

Unable to understand the reason.

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
    C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Amit/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.arch.core:android.arch.lifecycle.livedata.core:android.arch.lifecycle:android.arch.lifecycle.viewmodel:com.clevertap.unity:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.asynclayoutinflater:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.coordinatorlayout:android.support.cursoradapter:android.support.customtabs:android.support.customview:android.support.design:android.support.design.animation:android.support.design.bottomappbar:android.support.design.bottomnavigation:android.support.design.bottomsheet:android.support.design.button:android.support.design.canvas:android.support.design.card:android.support.design.chip:android.support.design.circularreveal:android.support.design.circularreveal.cardview:android.support.design.circularreveal.coordinatorlayout:android.support.design.color:android.support.design.dialog:android.support.design.drawable:android.support.design.expandable:android.support.design.floatingactionbutton:android.support.design.internal:android.support.design.math:android.support.design.navigation:android.support.design.resources:android.support.design.ripple:android.support.design.shape:android.support.design.snackbar:android.support.design.stateful:android.support.design.textfield:android.support.design.textfield:android.support.design.theme:android.support.design.transformation:android.support.design.typography:android.support.design.widget:android.support.documentfile:android.support.drawerlayout:android.support.interpolator:android.support.loader:android.support.localbroadcastmanager:android.support.print:android.support.v7.recyclerview:android.support.slidingpanelayout:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable:android.support.swiperefreshlayout:android.support.transition:android.support.viewpager:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.common:com.google.android.gms.gcm:com.google.android.gms.iid:com.google.android.gms.stats:com.google.android.gms.tasks:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:in.locomotion.plugins.login:com.aurodo.vehicles4d.resources -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.core.runtime-1.1.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.lifecycle.livedata-core-1.1.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.1.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.lifecycle.viewmodel-1.1.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\clevertapsdk-unity\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.asynclayoutinflater-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.cardview-v7-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.coordinatorlayout-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.cursoradapter-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.customtabs-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.customview-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-animation-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-bottomappbar-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-bottomnavigation-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-bottomsheet-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-button-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-canvas-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-card-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-chip-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-circularreveal-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-circularreveal-cardview-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-circularreveal-coordinatorlayout-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-color-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-dialog-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-drawable-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-expandable-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-floatingactionbutton-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-internal-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-math-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-navigation-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-resources-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-ripple-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-shape-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-snackbar-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-stateful-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-tabs-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-textfield-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-theme-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-transformation-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-typography-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-widget-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.documentfile-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.drawerlayout-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.interpolator-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.loader-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.localbroadcastmanager-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.print-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.recyclerview-v7-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.slidingpanelayout-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-compat-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-ui-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-utils-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-fragment-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-media-compat-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-v4-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.transition-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.viewpager-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-auth-15.0.1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-15.0.1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-15.0.1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-gcm-15.0.1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-wrapper-7.10.1\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-login-kit\res" -S "C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res"

    stderr[
    C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-textfield-28.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-v21\avd_hide_password.xml:22: note: generating nested resource com.aurodo.vehicles4d:drawable/avd_hide_password_1
    C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-textfield-28.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-v21\avd_hide_password.xml:57: note: generating nested resource com.aurodo.vehicles4d:drawable/avd_hide_password_2
    C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-textfield-28.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-v21\avd_hide_password.xml:73: note: generating nested resource com.aurodo.vehicles4d:drawable/avd_hide_password_3
    C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-textfield-28.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-v21\avd_show_password.xml:22: note: generating nested resource com.aurodo.vehicles4d:drawable/avd_show_password_1
    C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-textfield-28.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-v21\avd_show_password.xml:56: note: generating nested resource com.aurodo.vehicles4d:drawable/avd_show_password_2
    C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-textfield-28.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-v21\avd_show_password.xml:72: note: generating nested resource com.aurodo.vehicles4d:drawable/avd_show_password_3
    Failed to generate resource table for split ''
    C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius').

    ]
    stdout[
    Configurations:
     (default)

    Files:
      drawable\close.png
        Src: () C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable\close.png
      AndroidManifest.xml
        Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

    Resource Dirs:
      Type drawable
        drawable\close.png
          Src: () C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable\close.png
    Including resources from package: C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar
    applyFileOverlay for drawable
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_auth_dialog_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_auth_dialog_cancel_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_auth_dialog_header_background.xml            
    Processing image: C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable\close.png
        (processed image C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable\close.png: 45% size of source)  
        (new resource id design_layout_tab_text from C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-tabs-28.0.0-alpha1\res\layout\design_layout_tab_text.xml)
        (new resource id design_menu_item_action_area from C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Vehicles_Unity\Anwar\10-april\Vehicles10Apr2018\Vehicles\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.design-internal-28.0.0-alpha1\res\layout\design_menu_item_action_area.xml)
    ]
    exit code: 1
      at UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck(String[], String, String, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, BuildOptions, Boolean)
    UnityEditor.DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:165)
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods(Boolean, BuildOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:89)
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons(IBuildWindowExtension, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, BuildPlatform) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:885)
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:810)
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:415)
    System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object, Object[], Exception&)
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I changed the minimum-sdk =16 and target-sdk=27 in AndroidManifest.xml. Also, before this, I had installed build tools 25.0.2 and tried same as above but face same issues of repackaging.   Consistently got this : "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius')."

Comment: There was more to code, but that was not useful, so did not paste here. The core reason for the problem is mentioned above. Even if I change minimum-sdk=24, and target-sdk=27, then too same problem

Comment: Try the link i provided you .

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I installed multiple plugins, 1. Clevertap, 2. Google Play Services 3. Facebook SDK for facebook Login, 4. Google Analytics Plugin. Can these plugins be a problem?

Comment: Actually it could be a problem . For like Google Play Service. Maybe You could try install plugin 1 by 1 then build and see if what plugin is messing you up

Comment: Create a new and empty project without any plugin and see if you can build it.

Comment: I created a new empty project without any plugin and was able to build apk for Android. Seems plugin mix can be an issue. Any suggestions to handle this?

Comment: You said you are using Unity 28.1.1f1. You mean 2018? I will suggest you add your plugins one by one to that empty project and see which plugin will cause it to stop building.

Comment: yup, 2018. Let me try that too